# How to center the footnote table?

Tags: tables, captions

I started my thesis dissertation using "harvard-thesis.cls" template with this origninal file hosted here

https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd

My problem now is with the footnote table justification. The centering is not working, although I put this line in the .cls:

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

You can check and edit the chapter 1

https://es.sharelatex.com/project/58455964c0ba0b593dc919de

In particular, this is not working on this example:

```
    \documentclass{thesis}
        \beging{document}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \caption{Principales hashtags del movimiento 15M}
            \label{tab:hashtags15M}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}\toprule[1.5pt]
            \bf Hashtag & \bf Tweets & \bf Ratio*  \\\midrule
             acampadasol & 646.853 & 25,80\\
             spanishrevolution & 605.764 & 24,16\\
             15m & 572.047 & 22.82\\
             nolesvotes & 302.745 & 12,08\\
             democraciarealya & 242.903 & 9,69\\
             nonosvamos & 103.889 & 4,14 \\
             notenemosmiedo & 84.614 & 3,38\\
             yeswecamp & 56.938 & 2,27\\
             19j & 56.622 & 2.26 \\
             globalcamp & 37.024 & 1,48\\
             bcnsinmiedo & 37.024 & 1,48\\
             globalcamp & 35.877 & 1,43\\
             estoesreflexion & 31.220 & 1,25\\
             15mani & 28.891 & 1,15

            \bottomrule[1.25pt]
            \end {tabular}\par
            \caption*{*Porcentaje de Tweets respecto a la muestra. \\
            La relación tweet:hashtag suele ser de tipo 1:n.\\Muestra $=$ 2.507.027 tweets}
            \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `threeparttable` package seems to be a solution. Now new questions came up:

1. How to adjust now, automatically, the linewidht, just to adapt each cell content?
2. How to center the table if the linewidth is less than the document column?
3. How implement multicolumn?
4. How to increment the toprule, midrule and bottomrule width?

Here's one example:

```
\documentclass{harvard-thesis}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=\rmdefault, textfont=\rmdefault }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
    \toprule[1.5pt]
        \caption{Revisions}
         \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\linewidth}
                            p{0.15\linewidth}
                            p{0.15\linewidth}
                            p{0.15\linewidth}}
            \hline
                Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4          \\
            \hline
                Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{a} \\
                Cell 1  & Cell 1  & Cell 3  & Cell 4 \tnote{b} \\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[a] My Note.
                \item[b] My Other Note.
            \end{tablenotes}
         \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should first read this: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that A so-called **minimal working example** helps the poeple here to help you.

Comment: Your example uses '`thesis`' (of which there are several) but in the text you mention `harvard-thesis.cls`. Could you give us a link to where you've got the class file from?

Comment: Also, you've got two uses of `\caption`, the first of which works correctly and the second of which is I think meant to be a footnote. The example also doesn't compile properly if I switch to `article` and add `booktabs` and `caption` packages. That makes it hard to really know where the issue is: do you get any errors when compiling?

Comment: 1. The document https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd

Comment: The errors when I compile are in this sample document, ch 1 https://es.sharelatex.com/project/58455964c0ba0b593dc919de

Comment: sorry @samcarter...and all the community, just learning :-(

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable?lang=en may help

Comment: thanks @WillieWong. Using this *threepartable* package now. New questions came up. 1- How to adjust now, automatically, the linediwdht, just to adjust each cell content? 2- How to center the table if the linewidth is less than the document column? 3- How to adapt to a multicolumn style?

Comment: This site is a Q&A-site, not a forum, so each "post" should ideally be one question only. So editing your question to include new questions is not really the way to go. Also, your questions are vague (for example it is not easy to understand what you mean with "adapt to a multicolumn style"), and answers to most (or all) of them can readily be found by searching the site.